# Symfony2 update doctrine entity field only when dependent entity field changes

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, crud, lifecycle

Is there a pre-defined way in Symfony2 or Doctrine2 to run a specific piece of code. Either using an EventSubscriber or Service only when a specific entity field changes?

In my use case a user can create a new project. 
They can give the project a value in a specific chosen currency. 
This value is converted to a base currency that they have chosen.

The problem is that I only want to trigger that calculation/conversion when they either first create the project or when they only change the project value attribute.

I'm now using a solution where I subscribe to the doctrine postPersist event but this triggers the conversion if they for example only change the name of the project.

Edit: As Denis pointed out I should have clearly mentioned that I have this constraint in my composer.json for doctrine >=2.2.3,<2.4-dev

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks-event-argument) gives this example:

```
<?php
// ...

class User
{
    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $event)
    {
        if ($event->hasChangedField('username')) {
            // Do something when the username is changed.
        }
    }
}
```

Have you tried it?

P.S. It works only since Doctrine 2.4.

Comment: I know this exists in 2.4 but I'm looking for something similar in an earlier version. (constraint "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev")

Comment: @Simon I see, you should have mentioned it in the task. And it's not too late to do it right now, since not all participants will notice your comment here. And BTW, Doctrine 2.4 was released on 2013.09.11. So, it can be used in production. Why can't you upgrade?

Comment: I thought this was a constraint by Symfony and DoctrineBundle. If I change it to 2.4.3 my composer update fails due to constraints set by doctrine/doctrine-bundle.

Comment: @Simon, I had similar error when I upgraded to Symfony 2.3 (from 2.1) and somehow it downgraded my Doctrine :S . This is what I have now in my composer.json and it works. `"doctrine/orm": "2.4.2", doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",`

Comment: @DimitryK This is what I have and works perfectly         ```"symfony/symfony": "2.5.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.4.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2@dev"```

Comment: @Simon I am trying to stick with symfony 2.3 because it is LTS :)